# Get record from master table if alteast one record exists in slave/child tables using django api

Tags: python, django, postgresql

To elaborate

e.g.
I have two models "Subject" and "Question"

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want the list of active subjects having at least one active question.

I have done initial search and also checked django queryset api, but did not got answer.

I am not looking for raw sql query option.

I hope this clears the query. I have tried django api, but did not get expected result. I think this is very obvious query and there should be simple answer to it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just for the record, it would have been helpful if you had stated in your question what exactly you had tried, and described the actual, and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Subject.objects.filter(question__id__isnull=False).distinct()
```

You might even be able to simplify it to the following, but I'm too lazy to look up if it's correct or try it out:

```
Subject.objects.filter(question__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: Yes, I did try. But it is returning multiple duplicate rows.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.distinct()` to the queryset?

Comment: This is working hence accepting the answer, but I am not sure if it is good for performance. Usual cases might have 10-20 subjects and 500-10000 questions in db. Checking the first active question record exists will be sufficient for the purpose. May be you can comment on it.

Comment: With numbers of records in the orders of magnitude you wrote, the difference should be negligible, but as always, the only way to be certain is to measure it with real data.